# Add CSP security headers dynamically in Spring Scala with Vue app

Tags: spring, scala, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have this Spring http rules set on the server

```
// 'self' 'light-theme-hash' '?' 'dark-theme-hash'
  private val CssStyleCspPolicy =
    "'self' 'sha256-ELeESfcV3Z1sMrVQ47+tvTRmDX8QfJ90cdPQVhZDCJY=' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=' 'sha256-P6VWgDX817s5QKs30eW4WeIJVwK3O6UOpJEhvaevpWE=';"

  private def addSecurityHeaders(http: HttpSecurity): Unit = {
    http.csrf().disable()

    http
      .headers()
      .frameOptions()
      .sameOrigin()
      .xssProtection()
      .and()
      .contentSecurityPolicy(
        "default-src 'self' fallback no; " +
          "script-src 'self'; " +
          "form-action 'self'; " +
          "frame-ancestors 'self'; " +
          "style-src " + CssStyleCspPolicy +
          "style-src-elem " + CssStyleCspPolicy +
          "img-src 'self' data:; " +
          "font-src 'self';"
      )
  }
```

The problem is that everytime that some inline styles change, mostly due to a vuetify light/dark theme color change the sha hash also changes and I get this kind of errors in the browser and some styles are not applied

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "style-src-elem 'self'
> 'sha256-ELeESfcV3Z1sMrVQ47+tvTR1DX8QfJ90cdPQVhZDCJY='
> 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='
> 'sha256-P6VWgDX817s5QKs30eW4WeIJ1wK3O6UOpJEhvaevpWE='". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-P6VWgDX817s5QKs30eW4WeIJVwK3O6UOpJEhvaevpWE='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Is there a way besides removing the style-src and style-src-elem policies and maybe building the sha dynamically?